# Somar valores dentro da Matriz Bidimensional a partir da linha que o usuário escolher

Tags: java, matriz, array-multidimensional

No exercício eu tinha que criar uma **matriz bidimensional** e depois quando o usuário digitasse **0, 1 ou 2** para saber a **linha da matriz**, eu deveria somar os valores da linha e mostrar o resultado.

Eu gostaria de saber se dentro da matriz, se eu consigo somar de outra forma sem ter que colocar `matriz[0][0]`...`matriz[0][3]`. Pois em uma matriz muito grande, acredito eu que teria muito trabalho para fazer desse modo.

Segue meu exercício:

```
package arraysbidimensionais;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int matriz[][] = new int[3][3];
        int indicador;

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.println("Digite um valor: ");
                matriz[i][j] = input.nextInt();

            }

        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Matriz Completa");
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");

            }
            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Digite 0, 1 ou 2: ");
        indicador = input.nextInt();

        int soma = 0;
        if (indicador == 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                    soma = matriz[0][0] + matriz[0][1] + matriz[0][2];

                }

            }

            System.out.println("Soma da linha 0: " + soma);

        } else if (indicador == 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                    soma = matriz[1][0] + matriz[1][1] + matriz[1][2];

                }

            }

            System.out.println("Soma da linha 1: " + soma);

        } else if (indicador == 2) {

            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                    soma = matriz[2][0] + matriz[2][1] + matriz[2][2];

                }

            }

            System.out.println("Soma da linha 2: " + soma);

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retire os "if(indicador...)" e use o bloco assim:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                    soma = matriz[indicador][0] + matriz[indicador][1] + matriz[indicador][2];

                }

            }

            System.out.println("Soma da linha " + indicador + ": " + soma);
```

Comment: ah sim, verdade...Muito Obrigada.